# How to deal with different viewport sizes the best way?

Tags: javascript, css, mobile

I am Programming a webapp that uses a mobile-first design principle.

I have tested the design with my primary devices but then I discovered, that other devices with nearly the same display displays the page completely different.

The problem is because of the device-pixel-ratio, the app toggels to another media query and so the margins just look strange. On the Picture that does not look much, but on the device it really looks strange.

[image: Nexus 4 Simulated in Chrome]
[image: Nexus 5 Simulated in Chrome]

Is there a way I can modify the device-pixel-ratio within my javascript or css?